# python - formatting a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, formatting

I want to print a string in a sexy aligned way but I can't see what I'm doing wrong?

I would like to achieve this:

```
15     OBJECT (7)      Content Placeholder 5
17     BODY (2)        Text Placeholder 1
18     BODY (2)        Text Placeholder 2
23     OBJECT (7)      Content Placeholder 3
24     PICTURE (18)    Picture Placeholder 4
25     BODY (2)        Text Placeholder 6
```

My code:

```
for shape in slide.placeholders:
    print '{0:<5}  {1}      {2:<5}'.format(shape.placeholder_format.idx, 
                                           shape.placeholder_format.type, 
                                           shape.name)
```

But this is what I get

```
15     OBJECT (7)      Content Placeholder 5
17     BODY (2)      Text Placeholder 1
18     BODY (2)      Text Placeholder 2
23     OBJECT (7)      Content Placeholder 3
24     PICTURE (18)      Picture Placeholder 4
25     BODY (2)      Text Placeholder 6
```

FYI - doing this: print `'{0:<5} {1:<15} {2:<5}'.format(...)`

gives me this:

```
15    7               Content Placeholder 5
17    2               Text Placeholder 1
18    2               Text Placeholder 2
23    7               Content Placeholder 3
24    18              Picture Placeholder 4
25    2               Text Placeholder 6
```

It kinda eats into my middle column of text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the second element also to be left aligned, like this

```
print '{0:<5} {1:<15} {2}'.format(...)
```

Here, you say that the first column should be left aligned and the width is 5, second item also should be left aligned and the width is 15.

Comment: this method eats into my middle column of text for some reason, see update.

Comment: @Boosted_d16 What are the actual values of `shape.placeholder_format.type`? Please print them separately and include them in the question.

Comment: it's a <class 'pptx.enum.base.EnumValue'>

Comment: @Boosted_d16 Hmmm, they might have overriden the `__str__` or `__repr__` methods of that class to include both the name and number.

Comment: @Boosted_d16 If you see line number 284 in the [source code of that class](http://pydoc.net/Python/python-pptx/0.5.7/pptx.enum.base/), they return both the string and the number. You might want to try `'{0:<5} {1:s<15} {2}'` as well, so that you don't have to explicitly convert the value to string with `str`.